# How do I purchase stocks at a US IPO from overseas and as non-US citizen?

Tags: ipo, sweden

Can I still contact US brokers directly? I think you need to be a US resident to create an etrade.com account, right?

Comment: What country are you resident of.

Comment: I'm in Sweden and have a Swedish ETrade account (although now it's branded as a Danish bank Saxo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're outside the US then etrade will direct you to the most appropriate portal for your location - e.g., if I'm in Australia, I have to sign up for an account through the Singapore portal.

Whether taking out an account with etrade gets you access to US IPOs is another matter entirely. Foreigners can generally participate (if and when your particular etrade portal is participating), but your residency is the least of your worries. The size and longevity of your account with a broker like etrade is much more important when they decide who gets in and who misses out.

Comment: Is it possible for me from Europe to create an account on the US Etrade site? Or do I need a US bank account?

Comment: @Nicholas. There was an option to open a trading account for US securities if you are outside the US as well as being a foreign national (global.etrade.com/gl/products-services/open-an-account) Note that these are/were a specific US trade account, not a regular etrade account. However, the opening of such accounts is currently suspended with no indication of when they will reopen. Also note that it probably changes little with regards to IPOs.